# add data in this.state to use in another function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a delete method in reactJS. My logic is to get the data from the api, use that data in the `this.state` and call it from the `componentDidMount` to delete the data.

I can't figure out how to make at the this.state to display the data ID or so I can delete it.

When I click `Delete` button I get the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Anyone has an idea?

```js
class DeleteForm extends Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: ''
    }
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/zoom';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/zoom/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <button onClick={this.componentDidMount}>Delete</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `componentDidMount` as your function call, it's the react lifecycle, better to split up to avoid any confusion. for your problem, i've just answered in another issue, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727623/how-to-setstate-in-two-different-functions-in-react-js/61727893#61727893

Comment: You're not solving the problem I have on that question. I want my this.state to be updated with the data from the api.

Comment: Your error is in this line `axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/zoom/${this.state.id}`)`. The componentDidMount read `this` as `undefined` not an `object` because u haven't bind the function into your component. well try this one `componentDidMount = () => axios.delete()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have id in the response. You can do it like this.

```
class DeleteForm extends Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: ''
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/zoom';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    this.setState({
      id: data.id
    })
  }

  delete = () =>  {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/zoom/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      {this.state.id && <button onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>}
    )
  }
}
```

Your button will show up only when id is set.

Comment: I don't have ID on response, and that's the issue.

Comment: Can you paste the response you are getting in console.log

Comment: This is on my backend terminal `Executing (default): DELETE FROM `data` WHERE `id` = 'undefined'`

Comment: for the api http://localhost:8080/zoom what is the response you are sending? I mean console.log(data) in componentDidMount

Comment: The localhost:8080/zoom is my api filled with different data.

The error I get on console of the browser is 
`DELETE http://localhost:8080/zoom/ 404 (Not Found)`

`createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)`

Comment: Your id in state is empty initially that's why you are getting this error. You have to set id based on the first API call response in componentDidMount. It would be easy to pinpoint the issue if you make a small demo or post the response for the API.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for, to get the id in the state to work with the api.

My api has the following: `"id"`, `"subject"`, `"meetingid"`, `"password"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213614/discussion-between-chandan-kr-jha-and-angels7).